# Jquery Css Selector Add Value

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i reset a display:none and add some value here is the code

```
onclick="$('reason{$test->id}').css('display:block');
$('#reasonid{$test->id}').val(this.value);"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#reason{$test->id}")
    .css('display','block')
    .val(this.value);
```

Try that.

Comment: I think you have an extra ')' at the end of your snippet.

Comment: how can i use this with the chaining method like $("#reason{$test->id}")
    .css('display','block')).('#gett{$test->id}').val(this.value);

Comment: @jessegavin - D'oh! you're right - fixed.
@streetparade - you need to provide more detail, I don't understand what you're asking.